# Проблема с вызовом меню рёбер (Ctrl+E) в Blender

Tags: blender

В режиме редактирования выделяю рёбра меш-объекта, нажимаю Ctrl+E, и вместо появления меню рёбер, в инфопанели выводиться следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя в настройках для этого сочетания клавишь по умолчанию стояло и стоит (горячие клавиши не переназначал) именно вызов меню рёбер:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это видно и в меню меша:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В блендере работаю чуть больше недели, поэтому не смог самостоятельно разобраться. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как оказалось, проблему создавал сторонний софт, а именно QTranslate постоянно висящий в трее с такой же комбинацией клавишь, которой я по назначению не пользовался и поэтому не сразу догадался проверить.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего переназначили сочетание клавиш на копирование объектов. Нужно зайти в User preferences, вкладка Input. Выбрать поиск по клавиатурному сочетанию

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вбить в поиск `Ctrl e` и в списке найденого можно отыскать команду которая вызывается вместо меню. И восстановить стандартное сочетание клавиш

Comment: Это я сделал в первую очередь. Ничего подобного по этой команде в списке нет, но на всякий случай все равно отключал все что было с ней связано, результат тот же. Отключил все плагины, ведь некоторые тоже могут занимать дефолтные комбинации, но и это ни к чему не привело.

Comment: Пробовали load factory settings?